# What is format specifier for `long double`

Tags: c++, c

I am working on application which works on various flavors of Unix and Windows 32bit and 64bit OS.

I am using `long double` data type, When I do `sprintf()` and used `long double` with `%lf`  in it then it works fine with windows does not give any kind of error, however on Solaris platform it gives core dump.

Sample code for the same issue is as following.

```
void main(){
    string size = "16622";
    string sizeFact = "20";
    long long sizeLongLong = strtoll(size);
    int factInt = atoi(sizeFact);
    long double sizeLongDouble = (long double) sizeLongLong/pow(2, factInt);
    char buf[512];
    sprintf(buf, "%.3lf %s", sizeLongDouble, "str");    
}
```

As mentioned above code works fine on windows 32bit and 64bit however for sprintf it gives me core on Solaris.

I tried type casting in sprintf it worked fine.

```
sprintf(buf, "%.3lf %s", (double) sizeLongDouble, "str");
```

What is the format specifier for `long double`?

What is the mistake I am making here, am I using wrong format specifier because of which it is giving core?

Why do I need to type cast one more time in sprintf()?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For `long double` you should use format `"%Lf"`. Formatting with small L (i.e. `"%lf"`) have no effect on POSIX systems (see [the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html)).

Comment: I believe this depends on the compiler. Does `%Lf` work on all versions of `g++` and `gcc`?

Comment: I tried using LF it worked, Does it worked for all the version of g++, gcc and visual studio on all flavors of Unix platform (32 and 64bit) and windows platforms (32 and 64bit)?

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande It's specified in POSIX, so should work in all Unix or Unix-like environments.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that `%lf` vs. `%f` does make a difference for scans, it's only for printing where they are equivalent.

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande Both `l` and `L` should work in VisualC++ (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It was typo in my code it `"%Lf"` worked I was trying `"%LF"`

Comment: `%Lf` is in ISO C and ISO C++

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) makes this pretty clear:

> **L**
>
> A following **a, A, e, E, f, F, g**, or **G** conversion corresponds to a long double argument. (C99 > allows %LF, but SUSv2 does not.)

So, you should use `%Lf`.

Answer (score 2):

I would add this as a comment but I cannot do that yet. It is also important to note that you could also use the Exponential 'p' notation for `long double` in this way:

- Fixed-point notation: `%Lf`
- Exponential-notation: `%Le`
- p notation: `%La`

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the compiler I have seen `%Lf` and `%llf` try both and see which works. The `%lf` that you use is the format specifier for `double` not for `long double`. I believe on `g++` you should use `%llf`, while on visual studio it is `%Lf`.

Comment: `%Lf` is what you should use in standard C. `%llf` is invalid, but it's useful information if dealing with a nonconforming implementation.

Comment: I know this from computer science competitions where I always have problems with those. If using `llf` does not work, I use `Lf`. Still most of the time `llf` is the one that works. If I got a nickle each time I lost several because of that...