# value of double vs long double in C++

Tags: c++, double

in C++ I'm defining the following types:

```
double doubleType = 1.6e-300;
long double longDoubleType = 1.6e-300;
```

I'll then print the values using:

```
cout << "double is of size " << sizeof(doubleType) << " and value is " << doubleType << endl;
cout << "long double is of size " << sizeof(longDoubleType) << " and value is " << longDoubleType << endl;
```

my output reads:

```
double is of size 8 and value is 1.6e-300
long double is of size 12 and value is -1.43863e-264
```

Whats causing the difference in the interpretation of the values?

Comment: Well, [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/Cv1ZVA). Probably platform dependent...

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/ZeFnji).

Comment: @Rakete1111, long double is defined as platform dependent

Comment: Are you sure you used `cout` and not, say, `printf`?

Comment: Note that long double literals use the suffix L. It should be `long double longDoubleType = 1.6e-300L;`.

Comment: *"long double is of size 12"* That's unusual. What compiler on what platform do you use?

Comment: Try putting output after with `cout.precision(n)`!?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux But the implicit conversion from `double` literal to `long double` should not lose precision.

Comment: [I can reproduce this with printf](http://ideone.com/dzUv0X), by providing the wrong format specifier, which suggests that you've somehow got (part of) the bytes of the long double interpreted as a double. Again, are you sure you used `cout` in your actual test?

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Why is that unusual? I'd call that very usual on x86.

Comment: Also I get this output; `double is of size 8 and value is 1.6e-300` `long double is of size 16 and value is 1.6e-300`.

Comment: @KerrekSB iirc I have only ever seen 64 bit or 80 bit `long double`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You're confusing value bits with object bits.

Comment: @KerrekSB Why would you only use 80 value bits but store it in 96 bits?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Why is a the size of a struct not the sum of the sizes of its members?

Comment: That's padding but I do not see why there would be padding in a built in type.  a long double is not the same as a class type.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Every and any type can have padding (except `char`). The hardware processes 80-bit floats, but they need to be stored 4-byte aligned.

Comment: @KerrekSB Interesting.  I have never thought about it that way.  TIL

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem likely that you got this behavior with `std::cout`. More likely, you were using `printf` with the wrong format specifier, something like:

```
printf("%g", longDoubleType);
```

This is undefined behavior. It's permitted to do just about anything, but one of the common ways it plays out is that some of the bits of `longDoubleType` are interpreted as a `double` instead of a `long double`.

[With `printf`](http://ideone.com/uvANoe), I can reproduce your output. With `std::cout`, I can't.

Comment: I'm definitely using cout.  I'm also using the minGW (minimalist GNU for Windows) compiler.  My build command is "g++ main.cpp", nothing fancy.  I also tried using the "-std=c++11" option and I get the same results.  Can you check your build options, maybe I'm missing something you're including.

Comment: @user2600449: The minGW information helps. It looks like this is a [known problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537775/cout-long-double-issue) with minGW, stemming from a mismatch between the `long double` implementations used by minGW and the underlying Microsoft libraries. Other search results suggest it might be fixed in more recent versions (but it's probably not).

Comment: I saw some similar reports on some websites.  I just installed the latest minGW a few weeks ago, so its probably not fixed yet.  This seems like the most likely explanation.  :/